# Is there a way to prevent Enter key from returning a response in json from another page? Codeigniter Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, codeigniter

I am using ajax for my operations `Create` and `Update`

I can already create and update, but if I press or hit **Enter key** then this shows from another page which is kinda not look good to see, and it suddenly also create blank data after hitting **Enter** key.

```
{"success":false,"type":"update"}
```

For visual representation, here it what it looks like after hitting the **Enter key** on input fields

[image]

this is what my input is in my View

```
 <input type="text" name="group[]" id="group" placeholder="Enter your Choice" class="form-control" />
```

in my Controller

```
public function addGroup(){
    $result = $this->group_model->addGroup();
    $msg['success'] = false;
    $msg['type'] = 'add';
    if($result){
        $msg['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}


public function updateGroup(){
    $result = $this->group_model->updateGroup();
    $msg['success'] = false;
    $msg['type'] = 'update';
    if($result){
        $msg['success'] = true;
    }
    echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

And in Model

```
public function updateGroup(){
    $id = $this->input->post('txtId');
    $field = array(
    'group_name'=>$this->input->post('group')
    );
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('groups', $field);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}



public function addGroup(){
    $field = array(
        'group_name'=>$this->input->post('group'),
    );
    $this->db->insert('groups', $field);
    if($this->db->affected_rows() > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

> Ajax

```
$('#btnSave').click(function(){
        var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
        var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
        //validate form
        var group = document.getElementById('group').value;

        if(group.replace(/\s/g, "").length <=0 ) {
            swal("Submission fail!", "Enter the required field", "error");
            return false;
        }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'ajax',
                method: 'post',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                async: false,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.success){
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                        if(response.type=='add'){
                            var type = 'added'
                        }else if(response.type=='update'){
                            var type = 'updated'
                        }

                        swal("Success!", "You delete a Question!", "success");                          
                        showGroups();
                    }else{
                        alert('Error');
                    }
                },
                error: function(){
                    alert('Could not add data');
                }
            });

    });
```

Comment: where is your ajax code show that too ..

Comment: @BoominathanElango - updated my code above, you can see it at the bottom part. thanks!

Comment: The thing is you can disable enter key till you get proper response?

Answer (score 0):

> **Change**

```
$('#btnSave').click(function(){
    var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
    var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
    //validate form
    var group = document.getElementById('group').value;

    if(group.replace(/\s/g, "").length <=0 ) {
        swal("Submission fail!", "Enter the required field", "error");
        return false;
    }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                if(response.success){
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                    if(response.type=='add'){
                        var type = 'added'
                    }else if(response.type=='update'){
                        var type = 'updated'
                    }

                    swal("Success!", "You delete a Question!", "success");                          
                    showGroups();
                }else{
                    alert('Error');
                }
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Could not add data');
            }
        });

});
```

> **into**

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    var url = $('#myForm').attr('action');
    var data = $('#myForm').serialize();
    //validate form
    var group = document.getElementById('group').value;

    if(group.replace(/\s/g, "").length <=0 ) {
        swal("Submission fail!", "Enter the required field", "error");
        return false;
    }

        $.ajax({
            type: 'ajax',
            method: 'post',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function(){
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true);
            },
            success: function(response){
                if(response.success){
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                    if(response.type=='add'){
                        var type = 'added'
                    }else if(response.type=='update'){
                        var type = 'updated'
                    }

                    swal("Success!", "You delete a Question!", "success");                          
                    showGroups();
                }else{
                    alert('Error');
                }

            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Could not add data');
            }
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false);
```

return false;
            });

```
});
```

> Change **button** into **Submit**
>
> Hope this Helps !!

Comment: the data that is displayed where gone, and after clicking `alert('Error')` occurs.

Comment: Check Press F12 in Browser or Right Click on Browser > Inspect element >Network Check the result what exactly happening there

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(e){
    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //disable the button

    //.Your other code

    success: function(response){
            if(response.success){
                $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //enable the button

            }
    }
}
```

On CLicking the button disable the click event of submnit button which is default behaviour if you press Entern and enable it back if u get successfuly response.

In addition if you just want to disable enter key then u cn do it like this:

```
var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: method 1 is not working, after I click the textbox the `alert('Error')` shows

Comment: So you want to disable @MadaraCode Enter key right after typing in textbox?

Comment: hello! method 2 works, I addes this code `$('#choice_fill').keypress(function(e)
 {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if (keyCode === 13) { 
   e.preventDefault();
   return false;
  }
});` how can I add addition ids? so I will not type multiple `keypress` functions

Comment: @MadaraCode Just give class instead of ids and it will work you can accept the answer if it solved your problem